# Heine-Borel: Proving limit is inside each subdivision

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, real-numbers

For one direction of the Heine-Borel theorem I am working through a proof whose essence is dividing a set into subdivisions and from these forming a Cauchy sequence in order to study its limit.

What I strongly suspect is that this limit must be inside each subdivision, but the proof absolutely eludes me.

I will first provide below a terse write-up of my proof of one direction of Heine-Borel theorem (a few details are omitted in interest of brevity). **I am proving that closed and bounded implies compactness**.

---

**Proof**

$S$ non-empty, closed and bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $S$ is non-compact, then there is a cover such that $S \subset \mathcal{C} = \displaystyle \bigcup_i O_i$ but not for finite $i$ (each $O_i$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, together with Euclidean metric, bounded sets are totally bounded. Intersect $S$ with a finite number of balls of radius $1$. Then some $X_1 = S \ \cap B(p_1, 1) $ cannot be finitely coverable by $\mathcal{C}$.

Next intersect $X_1$ with a finite number of balls of radius $\frac 12$. Again some $X_2 = X_1 \ \cap B(p_2, \frac 12) $ is also not finitely coverable by $\mathcal{C}$.

Continue subdividing $S$ in this fashion with ever smaller radii and obtain:

> $ X_n = S \ \cap B(p_1,1) \ \cap B(p_2, \frac 12) \ \cap \ldots  \cap B(p_n, \frac 1n) $ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Define a sequence $(s_n)$ where $s_n \in X_n$. $(s_n)$ is Cauchy and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is complete, whence $s_n \to s \in S$ (because $S$ is closed).

But then $s$ is inside some ball $B(s,R)$ at $s$ of radius $R$ contained in some open $O_j$. It is possible to fit $X_m$ for some $m$ inside $B(s,r) \subset O_j$, whence we have a contradiction. Hence $S$ is compact and we are done. $\blacksquare$

---

> What I suspect must be true is that $s \in X_n$ for each $n$. If not,
> then $s \notin X_N $ for some $N$ and also not in $X_{N+k}$ for each
> $k\geq 1$.
>
> I figured that if I can find a ball in $X_N$ containing all $s_n$ for
> $n\geq N$ that does not intersect a particular ball around $s$, I can
> produce a contradiction.
>
> The problem is that I seemingly lack means to quantify the size of
> $X_N$, or yet harder, the point in $X_N$ nearest to $s$.
>
> In for instance the set $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb{R}$ that I iteratively
> bisect, I can quantify the distance between $s$ and its distance to
> the endpoint of $[0,\frac 1N]$ and thus separate $s$ from $X_N$. How
> could I achieve a similar separation with my subdivisions above?
>
> A poor attempt I made that doesn't fully cut it: For any real
> $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an integer $M \geq N$ such that $s_n \in
> > B(s_M,\varepsilon) $ when $n \geq M$.
>
> If $\varepsilon < d(s_M, s)$ then it is trivial to draw a ball at $s$
> not intersecting $B(s_M, \epsilon$).
>
> But if $\varepsilon > d(s_M, s)$, I need to somehow know the size of
> $X_N$ and this is where I am nonplussed.
>
> Can anyone see how this argument could be completed? I don't think it
> should be all too complicated as I am making it to be. Is there a
> simpler argument one could make?
>
> Is it perhaps not even true to begin with? It would certainly be
> easier if all subdivisions were closed sets but my instinct says that
> it shouldn't be necessary.
>
> Any hints or ideas appreciated, would love to crack this one on my own
> so kindly mind any spoilers :)

**EDIT**:

I think I just realized that it is not true in general by drawing this picture:

[image]

$s$ could be on the "border" of some $X_N$ and the sequence could approach $s$ toward the border of $X_N$ without touching it.

The sequence will converge to $s$ and $s \in S$, but $s$ need not lie in any $X_n$.

Comment: Hints: (1) try to make it clear exactly what you are trying to prove. (The Heine-Borel theorem  is an "iff" statement, but it is not clear from your proposed proof which direction of the iff you are trying to prove.) (2) try your ideas out for $n = 1$ first - that should make it easier to find any bugs.

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you for (1), I hope it is not ambiguous after my clarification now. As regards (2): You mean I could suppose $s \notin X_1$ and tinker with that?

Comment: The clarification is good. By (2), I was suggesting you try your ideas out in $\Bbb{R}$ first.

Comment: @RobArthan In $\mathbb{R}$ it is easy to separate $s$ from the endpoints of $X_N$. And from there we can draw a ball around $s$ that does not intersect $X_N$. Effectively we analyze the nearest point to $s$. In higher dimensions, it's unfortunately more tortuous than that it appears to me

Comment: I think I just realized it is not necessarily true when $S$ is intersected with open balls. However it is true with closed balls!

Comment: I am unsure what you are asking. Are you trying to work out why the statement "It is possible to fit $X_m$ for some $m$ inside $B(s,r) \subset O_j$" is true?

Comment: @K.Power No that part I understand. I suspected that the limit ought to be inside each subdivision $X_n$ and wanted to verify this. But the picture I provided in my edit demonstrates that it is not necessarily true when intersecting with open balls, which I was unable to readily realize at the outset.